# Fireworks on Motzei Shabbos

Tags: halacha, maariv, havdalah, motzei-shabbos, non-jewish-holidays

Municipal fireworks displays in the US are often held on Saturday night, just as it is getting dark -- i.e. right at tzeis hakochavim, time for Ma'ariv, Havdalah, etc.

Assuming there is a vantage point to view the fireworks within walking distance, is there any problem getting into position before Shabbos ends and postponing Ma'ariv, Havdalah, etc, until the fireworks are over?

Does it take something away from the honor of Shabbos to do this? What if it meant missing davening in a minyan?

Comment: What obligations do mean? Ma'ariv and Havdalah? You can make them later?

Comment: Maybe that's just the answer. I am wondering if it is appropriate to postpone them just to watch fireworks, especially if getting into position might have to take place on Shabbos itself, or if one might miss davening in a minyan.

Comment: If the problem is to miss davening in a minyan, then it's another question, has nothing to do with shabbos. According the havdalah - I don't think there is problem to postpone it. Actually, one can make havdalah even on the next day.

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified the question a bit. If you feel like that's a good answer, go ahead and post it.

Comment: I would ask another question for another situation: does it maximially honor Shabbos to spend its latter part positioning oneself to get good seats at the movie theatre, at the crack of motzoi shabbes?

Comment: ps you should consult a rav for guidance on this matter.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28935